# OpenTest: How to integrate server, actor and template in AWS CodeBuild for linux?

Tags: aws-codebuild, opentest

We have to integrate our OpenTest automation with AWS CodeBuild. How can we run server, actor and template session in one terminal in linux ?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a new test session by using the OpenTest CLI:

```
opentest session create --template <TEMPLATE_NAME> --wait --server <SERVER_IP>:<PORT>
```

For example:

```
opentest session create --template "My session template" --wait --server 1.2.3.4:3000
```

Of course, you have to make sure that:

- OpenTest is installed on the machine where AWS CodeBuild agent is running from and the `opentest` command in the system path - basically make sure the `opentest` command is available for your pipeline.
- The AWS CodeBuild agent machine has network access to the IP and port that the OpenTest server is running on.